# How to combine the CSS properties "left", "right", "top" and "bottom"?

Tags: css

I was just wondering if there is a way to combine the CSS properties `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom`.

For instance, if I would do this:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

I would be able to do like this:

```
some-property: 0 0 0 0;
```

or

```
some-property: 0;
```

Comment: There is no shorthand property for the positional properties.

Comment: That is not possible. That is not margin or padding.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still fresh and not well supported but exactly what you looking, the `inset: 5px`,
a new CSS Logical Properties value:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset

Answer (score 1):

Maybe define them using a CSS variable and you change it when needed:

```css
.tlbr {
  top:var(--v,0);
  bottom:var(--v,0);
  left:var(--v,0);
  right:var(--v,0);
}


.box {
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box tlbr"></div>
<div class="box tlbr" style="--v:20px"></div>
<div class="box tlbr" style="--v:-20px"></div>
<div class="box tlbr" style="--v:40px"></div>
```

Comment: This was not what I looked for, but it's a nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

**No** you cannot combine them together, but if you are using sass can you do something like:

```
@each $position in $positions{
        #{$position}: $value;
    }
```